# count the number of rows/columns using UI Automation

Tags: ui-automation

I am new to UI Automation. I am working on UIAutomation IPad for one of the clients. I need to perform the below activities
1. When we click on Products list page, I will see a tabular format with 2 rows and 3 columns where each product will be displayed (Product image, name, price, ratings, SKU). Here I need to check if the products are listed in 2X3 format.

1. The products list page should display the text as (Viewing 1-6 of 100) on the 1st page. I need to swipe to the left then it should display (Viewing 7-12 of 100) something like that.In this screen, the products could be of various categories (Plasma tv, Insignia tv etc) Here, I need to capture the 'Viewing' as regular expression and perform on any screen. How to do this?
2. For each of the 6 products displayed on the screen, there will be a button 'Add to compare'. I need to validate, 'Add to compare' is present for all the 6 images. How to do this one?
3. When I click on the category, screen loading will take few seconds. I have made use of target.delay(20), its working fine now, however, I want to validate if the next screen is loaded using the below method.
   On the 2nd screen, I am capturing a staticText. I will ask the code to wait until this staticText is visible. Is that makes sense?

Apologies for posting all the queries at a time, please bear with me,I am n